# Apostrophe breaks comments in lstlisting

Tags: listings, italic, code

I defined a command to simplify the writing of code listings of (pseudo-) C code:

```
\lstdefinestyle{c}{
language=C,
basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=L,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false
}

\lstnewenvironment{ccode}{
\mathligsoff\lstset{style=c}}{}
```

If I use the environment `ccode` everything works fine unless apostrophes are used:

```
\begin{ccode}
  int x';
  // use x
  x = 3;
\end{coode}
```

In this listing the comment is not printed in italics but in 'straight' characters. If I remove `'` or add another `'` the italics are restored. This is the complete .tex code:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{semantic}
\lstdefinestyle{c}{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  frame=L,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false}
\lstnewenvironment{ccode}{
\mathligsoff\lstset{style=c}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{ccode}
  int x';
  // hi there
  x = 3;
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The accepted answer works flawlessly for me. Just a hint for other readers: If no strings or characters need to be displayed -- and thus no code like 'a' or 'string' -- `\lstset{literate={'}{{'}}1}` will also do the trick.

Comment: The single quote is a string delimiter; so everything that comes after `x'` in your code gets typeset in the default string style (upright). Why do you use `'` there? Is it valid C code?

Comment: Ah sure, I forgot about that... No, it is pseudo-code. Maybe I should just use a similar looking character. Is it possible to use some arbitrary unicode sign inside a code listing?

Comment: Unicode is not supported by `listings`. Why not use a package dedicated to typesetting pseudo-code instead of `listings`?

Comment: Question: is `x'` some kind of placeholder in your C code?

Comment: Well it was easier to just adopt the listing :-)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jubobs commented while I was working on this answer, the problem is that `'` is treated as a string delimiter in `C`, so everything until the next `'` is considered part of a string. You can see this by setting `stringstyle=\itshape` or similar; everything following the `'` is shown as a string.

Discussion in the comments notwithstanding (I would recommend something better suited for pseudo-code instead of `listings` as well), if you must stick with using `listings` one solution is to define your own language `pseudoc` as a copy of `c` as defined in `lstdrvrs`, and change the `'` character from a `b`-type delimiter to a `m`-type (MATLAB-style) delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

% modified ANSI C definition; copied from lstdrvrs.dtx
\lstdefinelanguage{pseudoC}%
  {morekeywords={auto,break,case,char,const,continue,default,do,double,%
      else,enum,extern,float,for,goto,if,int,long,register,return,%
      short,signed,sizeof,static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,%
      void,volatile,while},%
  sensitive,%
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},%
  morecomment=[l]//,% nonstandard
  morestring=[b]",%
  morestring=[m]',% changed from `b' to `m'
  moredelim=*[directive]\#,%
  moredirectives={define,elif,else,endif,error,if,ifdef,ifndef,line,%
  include,pragma,undef,warning}%
}[keywords,comments,strings,directives]%

\lstdefinestyle{pseudoc}{
language=pseudoC,
basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=L,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
}

\lstnewenvironment{ccode}{
\lstset{style=pseudoc}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{ccode}
  int x';
  // use x
  x = 3;
  y = 'a string'; // aside: this would be a compiler error :-)
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

I added the last line of the listing to make sure normal string behavior is preserved:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's one workaround. Nothing against your answer, but I think presenting that as pseudocode can be confusing. The quote in `x'` might lead students to believe that it's valid C syntax.